# setPasswordFromListString() not saving password

Tags: scala, lift, protouser

I'm writing a function in my `User` class (which inherits from `ProtoUser`) to bootstrap an admin user for my Scala Lift application:

```
def generateAdminUser():Boolean = {
  if (User.findAll(By(User.admin, true)).length == 0) {
    val pw = Props.get("firstadmin.password") openOr "hilariouslybadpassword"
    val admin = User.create
                    .lastName(Props.get("firstadmin.lastName") openOr "Lady")
                    .firstName(Props.get("firstadmin.firstName") openOr "DeFalt")
                    .email(Props.get("firstadmin.email") openOr "newinstall@mydomain.org")
                    .validated(true)
                    .setPasswordFromListString(pw::Nil)
                    .admin(true)
                    .saveMe
  } else {
    false
  }
}
```

Everything seems to be being save except for the password. When I look at the database:

```
id  lastname    firstname   email               locale  timezone    password_pw password_slt    biography   validated   uniqueid    superuser   admin_c
1   Lady        DeFalt      testemail@gmail.com en_US   US/Pacific  *           AE3MQZIX2KUB2ZMR        1   V25VPDIV43BW4HAATP1XMMV152PEWX3L    0   1
```

The `*` is clearly wrong (signing up through the normal code path proves this out: it should be a salted hash of the pw), but I'm not getting anything in my `console.devmode.log`, nor on my console. I'm attempting to be able to programmatically add users, but I'm not sure why this is failing? Being pretty new to Scala I'm not sure the best way to diagnose this: I've followed the code pathway as much as I can, but am a bit lost in the maze of ProtoUser/MegaProtoUser/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `firstadmin.password` set in your properties file?

I haven't used `ProtoUser` myself, but looking at the code - in the [`setFromAny`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/b401fcbab98d21542c022bffdc07d464e901fba2/persistence/record/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/record/field/PasswordField.scala#L63) method on `PasswordField`, it looks like the list needs to have the password twice in order to validate and hash.

Something like this may help:

```
setPasswordFromListString(pw::pw::Nil)
```

Also, there is a [default minimum length](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/b401fcbab98d21542c022bffdc07d464e901fba2/persistence/record/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/record/field/PasswordField.scala#L106) of the password which is [`5`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/b401fcbab98d21542c022bffdc07d464e901fba2/persistence/record/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/record/field/PasswordField.scala#L34) characters. If [validation fails](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/b401fcbab98d21542c022bffdc07d464e901fba2/persistence/record/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/record/field/PasswordField.scala#L53), it seems it will default to a [default value](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/8ccaa277ae37324ea6573b714621c14cf33690b8/persistence/record/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/record/Field.scala#L218).

Comment: That worked! The password was set in the prop file, but the openOr should have handled it if not. It does seem like it does the validation deeper in and thus needs both pws. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped. The reason I asked about the password being set in the properties file was mostly to see if it was perhaps something less than 5 characters since `hilariouslybadpassword` was most definitely longer.